# org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Connection refused: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:80;

Tags: java, spring-webflux, junit5

Small question on unit test with Junit5 + Spring WebClient please.

I have a basic `@Service` class with an `@Autowired` WebClient.

```
@Autowired private final WebClient webClient;
private MyAtServiceClass(WebClient webClient) {
 this.webClient = webClient;
}

    public Mono<MyPojo> sendHttpRequestToSomewhere(String payload) {
        return webClient.mutate().baseUrl("http://...").build().post().body(BodyInserters.fromValue(payload)).retrieve().bodyToMono(MyPojo.class);
    }
```

Since I just want to unit test, I am doing some “mock” with the following in my test class:

```
String payload = getSomeHardedCodedJsonPayload();
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .exchangeFunction(clientRequest ->
                Mono.just(ClientResponse.create(HttpStatus.OK)
                        .header("content-type", "application/json")
                        .body(payload)
                        .build())
        ).build();

MyAtServiceClass myAtServiceClass     = new MyAtServiceClass(webClient);
Mono<MyPojo> mono = myAtServiceClass.sendHttpRequestToSomewhere();
assertEquals(“foo”, mono.block().getFoo());
```

However, when I am running the unit test, expecting it to just return me my dummy, I am getting the connection refused exception below.

What would be the root cause please?

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Connection refused: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:80; nested exception is io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:80

    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:137)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Request to POST /somewhere [DefaultWebClient]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:137)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:70)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4046)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:221)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:221)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:221)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:204)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.whenError(FluxRetryWhen.java:224)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenOtherSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:273)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:413)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:250)
        at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:491)
        at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.tryEmitNext(EmitterProcessor.java:299)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManySerialized.tryEmitNext(SinkManySerialized.java:97)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalManySink.emitNext(InternalManySink.java:27)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:189)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:189)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect$ClientTransportSubscriber.onError(HttpClientConnect.java:306)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:189)
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onError(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:166)
        at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.AbstractPool$Borrower.fail(AbstractPool.java:427)
        at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.lambda$drainLoop$5(SimpleDequePool.java:310)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(FluxDoOnEach.java:186)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:189)
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnectionAllocator$PooledConnectionInitializer.onError(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:565)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:192)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:259)
        at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector$MonoChannelPromise.tryFailure(TransportConnector.java:464)
        at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector$MonoChannelPromise$1.tryFailure(TransportConnector.java:515)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:321)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:337)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:707)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1703)

        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
        at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:80
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:707)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Above is the entire stack trace.

Thank you

Comment: is it possible for you to share what `sendHttpRequestToSomewhere` does?

Comment: yup, updated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unrelated to you Problem, but maybe it helps someone that steps into the same trap as I did (although you might know this, as I actually did).

As stated in multiple tutorials, you have to pay close attention to the version of `.uri(...)` method you use.

More details about the `uri(...)` versions can be found in the Spring API: [WebClient.UriSpec](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.UriSpec.html#uri(java.net.URI))

If you use e.g. `.uri(URI)` you are overwriting any URL that you might have specified early (using e.g. `.baseUrl("http://localhost:8888")`), so if you just want to **append** a path (e.g. `/my-service/booking`) to your base url you must not use this overloaded method, otherwise you will miss the `host` and/or `port`, hence the above mentioned error message.

Comment: Thanks for that detail. That was the source of my grief.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your test is failing, though it looks to me as if the stubbed out exchange filter is not working the way it should. As a result, it is trying to make an api call when it shouldn't.

Below is an example unit test using the same mechanism you have used to stub out a web client call. I can verify this test passes as expected. This may provide some help in working out why your test is having an issue.

```
@Test
void webClientTest() {
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .exchangeFunction(clientRequest ->
                    Mono.just(ClientResponse.create(HttpStatus.OK)
                            .header("content-type", "application/json")
                            .body("test")
                            .build())
            ).build();

    Mono<String> stringMono = webClient.mutate().baseUrl("http://fakeUrl.com")
            .build()
            .post()
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue("abc"))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);

    StepVerifier.create(stringMono)
            .expectNext("test")
            .verifyComplete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that, create `WebClient` double that points to a `MockWebServer`.

See this post https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mocking-webclient

`MockWebServer` makes it really ease to stub any responses for testing.

If you need to talk to multiple endpoints, it's common to create a different `WebClient` instance per base URL. That way you wouldn't be mutating the WebClient in the methods that use it.  Consumers of that WebClient dependency would just specify the path they need to call. So then, when passing in a test double, it would be set up with a base url pointing the MockWebServer and the consuming class (under test) wouldn't know any different.